# To insert multiple dictionaries as values into a single key

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I need a set of nested dictionaries in the form {a:{}{b:{},{c:{}}}} where a,b and c are the keys. I have tried the following code.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def dictizeString(string,dictionary) :
    while string.startswith('/'):
        string = string[1:]
    parts = string.split('/',1)

    if len(parts)>1:
        branch = dictionary.setdefault(parts[0],[dict()])
        dictionary[parts[0]].append(dict())
        dictizeString(parts[1], branch)
    else:
        if dictionary.has_key(parts[0]):
            dictionary[parts[0]]=dict()
        else:
            dictionary[parts[0]]=[dict()]
            dictionary[parts[0]].append(dict())               


d={}

dictizeString('/a/b/c/d', d)
print d
```

Execution of this code results in an error ''list' object has no attribute 'setdefault''. The code works for the first iteration(i.e for a) but throws the above error for the second iteration(i.e b).

The append functionality works for the else section in the last 6 lines of the code.I tried to use the same logic in the if case, but it is throwing an error.

Comment: How do you want the output to look like when you print d?

Comment: @dopstar I wanted it to be like this {a:{}{b:{},{c:{}}}} on print d. Joshua's minor change in my code was what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def dictizeString(string,dictionary) :
    while string.startswith('/'):
        string = string[1:]
    parts = string.split('/',1)

    if len(parts)>1:
        branch = dictionary.setdefault(parts[0],[dict()])
        dictionary[parts[0]].append(dict())
        dictizeString(parts[1], branch[1]) # <--- branch -> branch[1]
    else:
        if dictionary.has_key(parts[0]):
            dictionary[parts[0]]=dict()
        else:
            dictionary[parts[0]]=[dict()]
            dictionary[parts[0]].append(dict())               


d={}

dictizeString('/a/b/c/d', d)
print d
```

What you have on line 7 was a statement setting the default to be a *list* of dictionaries, but then you try to stick into the function where it is expecting a dictionary.

Comment: Perfect!! Exactly what I wanted. It did take me time to realize that the return value of a .setdefault is a key,value pair.

Comment: Glad to help, but I was wrong originally, it doesn't return a <key, value> pair. You were just creating a list as the value and appending to it.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to access the values using the key in this nested dictionaries?Or is a recursion by breaking the directory structure for ex. a/b/c/d as dict[a][b][c][d] the way to go?

Comment: dict[a][b][c][d] is the way to go. There really is no mechanism in python for the behavior you want if I understand correctly, but never fear! The most you'll ever need to recurse in the dictionary is `log n` where n is the number of files in you dictionary, so your total run-time complexity is `O(log n)` (assuming O(1) dictionary lookups) which is still very good.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have found an answer, but you can also do:

```
def dictizeString(path, dictionary):
    keys = path.lstrip('/').split('/')
    current_key = None
    for key in keys:
        if current_key is None:
            current_key = dictionary.setdefault(key, {})
        else:
            current_key = current_key.setdefault(key, {})

d = {}
dictizeString('/a/b/c/d', d)
print d
```

The output becomes: `{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}}}}}`